# Integration of a triple integral

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int_{z=0}^4\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=2y}^2{cos(x^2)\over \sqrt{z}}dxdydz$$ 
by changing the order of integration.

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I have no idea how to integrate cos(x^2) so I think by changing the order of integration it's meant to get rid of that problem?? Maybe?

Comment: I can't seem to get the right order though because I keep running into the problem associated with that cos(x^2).

Comment: I guess the best thing you would like to do is integrate first with respect to either $z$ or $y$. But that requires you to know what the solid you are integrating it over. Hint, the solid should look like a wedge. Though I'm not the best at drawing the image, but reading the limits of the integrals and translating that into what the solid should look like will be very useful in this problem.

Comment: I'll add another hint, but it would be helpful if you can convince yourself that the following limits are true: $\int_0^4 \int_0^2 \int_0^{\frac{x}{2}} \frac{\cos(x^2)}{\sqrt{z}} dy dx dz$. One way to see how I got this is suppose that you fix some value $z \in [0,4]$, the double integral (inner two integral) is over the region which is a triangle.

Comment: Could you please tell which integral belongs to which variable?

Comment: I can't edit the above equation for some reason, but the inner most integral, you're integrating with respect to $y$ since you have the differential $dy$, the next is with respect to $x$, then the last is with respect to $z$.

Comment: @Tzimmo $\displaystyle\color{green}{\int_0^4}\color{red}{ \int_0^2}\color{blue}{ \int_0^{\frac{x}{2}}} \frac{\cos(x^2)}{\sqrt{z\;}} \color{blue}{\operatorname dy} \color{red}{\operatorname dx}\color{green}{\operatorname dz}$

Comment: The inner most integral has $y$ in its borders, so you can't be integrating with respect to $y$ then.

Comment: @Graham, nice. I didn't know you can color code those.

Comment: @Faolan, you're welcome :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{2y}^{2}\cos(x^2)\,dx\,dy =\int_{0}^{2}\int_{0}^{\frac{x}{2}}\cos(x^2)\,dy\,dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2}2x\cos(x^2)\,dx=\frac{\sin(4)}{4}.$$